# Displaying REST API data on Charts using ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I am new to Angular and Ionic. Currently I am able to display static data on charts. But cannot figure out how do I display the data on a REST API using charts. following is the code that I currently have. I am not sure on how to integrate the data that I get from the API to the charts since the data being displayed on the charts is not inputed in the html file. If it were, I could enter the data using {{}}. However, since the data being displayed is in the ".ts" file.[This what I currently see: chart and a list of the API data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWn0o.png)

home.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <chart [options]="chartOptions" style ="display: block" type="chart"></chart>
  <br>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let message of messageList"> {{message.Date}} and {{message.message}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {MessageServiceProvider} from '../../providers/message-service/message-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  chartOptions: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private messageServiceProvider:MessageServiceProvider) {

    this.getMessages();

    this.chartOptions={
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
    }
  }

  messageList=[];



  getMessages(){
    this.messageServiceProvider.getMessages().subscribe(data => this.messageList=data.Items);
  }

}
```

message-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MessageServiceProvider {
  private url:string="https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello MessageServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getMessages(){
    return  this.http.get(this.url)
      .do(this.logResponse)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.catchError);
  }

  private catchError(error:Response){
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server Error");
  }
  private  logResponse(res: Response){
    console.log(res);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response){
    return res.json();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact output of your API? Is the API response JSON?

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Yes it is. Here is the API: https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries , and here is the data in it: {"Items":[{"Date":1499896074486,"message":"yo"},{"Date":1499977824999},{"Date":1499976641492},{"Date":1499976928878,"message":"July 13th"},{"Date":1499896774918},{"Date":1499883376762,"message":"yo"},{"Date":1500311063237,"message":"17th July"}],"Count":7,"ScannedCount":7}

Comment: I'm a tad confused, because your API response data doesn't seem to have anything to do with the charts you are creating? And some of your response data only has dates, with no message. How would we be able to chart that?

Comment: The charts that were created have static data (demo/example) in them. I am not sure on how to replace that with code that would display the API data. I am still learning and just want to learn how to display API data in the chart.

Comment: First of all, your data lacks some values and it should be parsed before using. Could you provide us with a working demo?